# What is PHP function overloading for?

Tags: php

In languages like Java, overloading can be used in this way:

```
void test($foo, $bar){}
int test($foo){}
```

Then if you called `test()` with 2 arguments e.g `test($x, $y);`, the first function would be called. If you passed only 1 argument e.g `test($x);`, the 2nd function would be called.

From the manual it seems that php 5 does have overloading, but what is it for? I can't seem to understand the manual on this topic..

Comment: See also [Why PHP doesn't support function overloading?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/190550/84349).

Comment: You can use overloadable class in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading/27231803#27231803

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[PHP's meaning of overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/overload.examples.basic.php) is different than Java's. In PHP, overloading means that you are able to add object members at runtime, by implementing [some of the `__magic` methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), like `__get`, `__set`, `__call`, `__callStatic`. You load objects with new members.

> Overloading in PHP provides means to
>   dynamically "create" properties and
>   methods. These dynamic entities are
>   processed via magic methods one can
>   establish in a class for various
>   action types.

An example:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        echo "Called method $method";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;

$foo->bar(); // Called method bar
$foo->baz(); // Called method baz
```

And by the way, PHP supports this kind of overloading since PHP 4.3.0. The only difference is that in versions prior to PHP 5 you had to explicitly activate overloading using the [`overload()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/overload.examples.basic.php) function.

Comment: What can be any possible advantages of that type of overloading whose example you gave???

Comment: One scenario in which `__call()` proved to be very useful was when I built a currency converter class. Instead of calling `$converter->convert(2, 'EUR', 'USD');` you could actually call `$converter->convertEurToUsd(2);`, which is much more readable in my opinion. You may take a look at my sources: http://github.com/igstan/php-utils/blob/master/tests/CurrencyConverterTest.php http://github.com/igstan/php-utils/blob/master/src/CurrencyConverter.php

Comment: I use this method for a dynamic LINQ-like interface to my database. So  I can do things like $db->Select('table')->col_1[$value]->col_2[$value]->Merge('col_1'); So all of the __calls(). Get passed through to the correct handling class (i.e. SQL, File, Xml).

Comment: Many PHP ORM libraries use the __get and __set methods to do what null is talking about.

Comment: Your currency converter code is very neatly written and formatted! What formatting guidelines do you follow when you write your code?

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciated. I mainly use the PEAR/Zend Framework coding conventions. I keep lines no longer than 79 chars, methods as short as possible and I line up variable declarations in columns. Anyway, GitHub's syntax highlighter has its merits too :)

Comment: That's a clever little solution there, Ionut.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to overload a function like in Java, don’t specify any arguments and use the [`func_num_args`](http://docs.php.net/func_num_args) and [`func_get_args`](http://docs.php.net/func_get_args) function to get the number of arguments or the arguments themselves that were passed to that function:

```
function test() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    switch (count($args)) {
        case 1:
            // one argument passed
            break;
        case 2:
            // two arguments passed
            break;
        default:
            // illegal numer of arguments
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To over load a function simply do pass parameter as null by default,

```
class ParentClass
{
   function mymethod($arg1 = null, $arg2 = null, $arg3 = null)  
   {  
     if( $arg1 == null && $arg2 == null && $arg3 == null ){ 
        return 'function has got zero parameters <br />';
     }
     else{
       $str = '';
       if( $arg1 != null ) 
        $str .= "arg1 = ".$arg1." <br />";

       if( $arg2 != null ) 
        $str .= "arg2 = ".$arg2." <br />";

       if( $arg3 != null ) 
        $str .= "arg3 = ".$arg3." <br />";

       return $str;
      }
   }
}

// and call it in order given below ...

$obj = new ParentClass;

echo '<br />$obj->mymethod()<br />';
echo $obj->mymethod();

echo '<br />$obj->mymethod(null,"test") <br />';
echo $obj->mymethod(null,'test');

echo '<br /> $obj->mymethod("test","test","test")<br />';
echo $obj->mymethod('test','test','test');
```