# Function argument with default value preceding an argument without default value: what happens?

Tags: php, function, arguments

(Perhaps this question has already been asked before, but I can't find it.)

What happens if you have an argument with default value preceding an argument without default value in PHP? Just like this:

```
function myfunction($foo = 12, $bar) {
    ...
}
```

- Does PHP give errors and if yes, on which error reporting level?
- What happens when you call `myfunction("hello")` with only one argument?

Comment: Have you tried before asking this question ?

Comment: I just want to know all ins and outs and the reason why you can't overload functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will output a warning, not an error, namely:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 in call to myfunction() in FILE on line LINENO
```

If you call `myfunction("hello")`, `$bar` is undefined, so it will either be an empty string or NULL, and `$foo = "hello"`. It will only raise a warning though, so your script will still execute.

Why don't you just switch the order of the parameters?

**Edit:** Here is a good explanation of why it is not possible to overload standalone functions in PHP:
[PHP function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading)

Comment: What you're referring to is function overloading, no? If that's the case, you can overload methods in a class, but not standalone functions, like so: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: I don't like the argument names to be misleading. Say I have `function cr_name($firstname, $infix, $lastname)`. It would be weird to mix up the order of arguments. For example, I don't like to input `"Leonardo", "Caprio", "di"`. Instead, I want to input it as the human logical order (Leonardo, di, Caprio). But if a name has no infix (e.g. George Clooney), I prefer to input it as `"George", "Clooney"`, skipping the `$infix` argument.

In Java, you *can* achieve that, defining 2 methods with the same name. It's called overloading.

Comment: Thank you, @nickb, I got it. I have created the following code, which appears to work:

`public function createname() {
$this->__call(__FUNCTION__, func_get_args());
}

public function __call($name, $arguments) {
switch ($name) {
case "createname":
switch (count($arguments)) {
case 2:
$this->firstname = $arguments[0];
$this->infix = "";
$this->lastname = $arguments[1];
break;
case 3:
$this->firstname = $arguments[0];
$this->infix = $arguments[1];
$this->lastname = $arguments[2];
break;
}
break;
}
}`

Notice: the empty function `createname()` is only for the editor to recognise my function.