# php redeclaring function like in java

Tags: java, php, overloading, redeclare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading)

I want to redeclare function such like this:

```
class Name{
    function a(){ something; }
    function a($param1){ something; }
}
```

but it returns

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Name::a()
```

In java it just works. How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: This answers explains it pretty nicely : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4697712/1606729

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use default parameters:

```
class Name{
    function a($param1=null){ something; }
}
```

If no parameter is passed to `Name::a()` it will assign a $param1 has a value of `null`. So basically passing that parameter becomes optional. If you need to know if it has a value or not you can do a simple check:

```
if (!is_null($param1))
{
 //do something
}
```

Comment: It's so bredsive cable... =( But thanks! It works...

Answer (score 4):

You won't redeclare a function. Instead you can make an argument optional by assigning a default value to it. Like this:

```
function a($param1 = null){ something; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Function arguments to not uniquely identify a function. In Java the arguments are strictly defined. This allows the compiler to know which function you are calling.

But, in PHP this is not the case.

```
function a()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

It's possible to create function that has no arguments define, but still pass it arguments.

> a("hello","world")

would output

> hello world

As a result, PHP can't tell the different between a() and a($arg). Therefore, a() is already defined.

PHP programmers have different practices to handle this single function problem.

You can define an argument with default values.

> a($arg = 'hello world');

You can pass mixed variable types.

```
 function a($mixed)
 {
     if(is_bool($mixed))
     {
         .....
     }
     if(is_string($mixed))
     {
         .....
     }
 }
```

My preference is to use arrays with defaults. It's a lot more flexible.

```
 function a($options=array())
 {
       $default = array('setting'=>true);
       $options = array_merge($default,$options);
       ....
 }

 a(array('setting'=>false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately PHP does not support Method overloading like Java does. Have a look at this here for a solution: [PHP function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading)
so `func_get_args()` is the way to go: