# Why do I get an error when I declare 2 methods with the same name but different signatures?

Tags: php, polymorphism

In the following script I declare two methods with the same name *calculate* but different signatures. But I get an error on declaration: 
`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Tester::calculate() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tester.php on line 7`. Why is that ? Php doesn't support this type of polymorphism ?

```
<?php
class Tester {
    public function calculate() {
        echo 2*2;
    }

    public function calculate($var_1,$var_2) {
        echo $var_1*$var_2;
    }
}

$obj = new Tester();
$obj->calculate();
echo "<br />";
$obj->calculate(5,4);
```

Comment: `public function calculate($var_1 = 2,$var_2 = 2)`? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php function overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP != (Java, C++, C#, VB.Net)

Although PHP borrows heavily from Java, there are some big differences between the two (and other OOP languages). One big one is you can't have methods using the same names with different parameters. You either need to:

- Use [default argument variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)
- Use different methods names
- Extend a parent/abstract class (a.k.a. [inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)) and then you can use [polymorphism](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-and-applying-polymorphism-in-php/)

Comment: PHP doesn't borrow from Java.  PHP borrows from C/C++, and Java borrows from C/C++.  PHP and Java were released roughly the same time and should be considered "sibling" languages.