# Flexible function parameters, how to do it with a good practise?

Tags: php

```
function query($query, $cacheType, $cacheDuration, $responseType)

$query = Query to be executed.
$cacheType = Memcached etc.
$cacheDuration = Duration of cache.
$responseType = MySQL response type. (e.g array, json etc)
```

1. I don't want to use cache, but expect to be JSON. How can I pass those 2 parameters?
2. If I set cacheType to "Memcached", how can I ensure a $cacheDuration is set to a valid integer?
3. If I add a fifth parameter to query function (e.g $fifth), how can I add it without breaking the calls used in entire website? They still give 4 parameters, but query updated to be 5 parameters.

I'm looking for "good practise" responses mostly, otherwise I know passing NULL values to params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$paramsArray = array();
$paramsArray['query'] = 'Query to be executed.';
$paramsArray['cacheType'] = 'Memcached etc.';
$paramsArray['cacheDuration'] = 'Duration of cache.';
$paramsArray['responseType'] = 'MySQL response type. (e.g array, json etc)';

echo query($paramsArray);

function query($paramsArray = array()) {

  $query = $paramsArray['query'];
  $cacheType = $paramsArray['cacheType'];
  $cacheDuration = $paramsArray['cacheDuration'];
  $responseType = $paramsArray['responseType'];

  // Your query operations with $query, $cacheType, $cacheDuration, $responseType
}
```

Comment: More preferable like `function query($query,$paramsArray = array())`, as query must be compulsory & imp in this function. btw +1 about to give the same answer.

Comment: Is using arrays the only option?

Answer (score 0):

use fifth parameter like this by setting default value, it will not break existing function call.

```
function query($query, $cacheType, $cacheDuration, $responseType, $fifth = NULL)
```

you can call this function with 4 parameter also

```
echo query($query, $cacheType, $cacheDuration, $responseType);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to use cache, but expect to be JSON. How can I pass those
>   2 parameters?

Didn't understand.

> If I set cacheType to "Memcached", how can I ensure a $cacheDuration
>   is set to a valid integer?

I probably didn't understand that one either but you can just validate with the is_int() function.

> If I add a fifth parameter to query function (e.g $fifth), how can I
>   add it without breaking the calls used in entire website? They still
>   give 4 parameters, but query updated to be 5 parameters. I'm looking
>   for "good practice" responses mostly, otherwise I know passing NULL
>   values to params.

I was just going to tell you that you could overload the function, but I just found out that it's not supported in php ([PHP function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading)), so you'd probably be good adding a fifth parameter with a default value of `null` and just doing whatever you want when `$fifth != null`

Comment: 1. query($query, 'JSON'); 2. query($query, 'MEMCACHED', (Need an integer here or exception.)) 3. That's not something I want to do.