# Does PHP have a provision for 'method overloading', just like java and some other programming languages? If not, is there an alternative?

Tags: php, overloading

I have scenario in my current work that requires overloading a method i.e having a method with the same name but different parameter requirement. And since i have done this in java, i was wondering if php have something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, not based on separate function declarations and parameters passed (like you see in Java).  See here for a thorough explanation and alternatives:

**[PHP function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading)**

Comment: In future, if this is the same question, please flag it as a duplicate instead of posting an answer that simply points there.