# Is it possible to overload a constructor in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have a question. I have some experience with OOP, but I am new to PHP(OOP). I am trying to learn it. Is it possible 
to overload a constructor?

In other languages it's possible to overload the constructor but in php not?
I tried but my I got the following message from my IDE:
"method with same name already defined in this class"

```
class testClass{

    public $param1 = "";
    public $param2 = "";

    public function __construct($param1, $param2){        
        $this->param1 = $param1;
        $this->param2 = $param2;

    }

    public function __construct($param1){
        $this->param1 = $param1;
        //ToDO use function to set param2
    }
}
```

Comment: [Nope overloading is not supported within PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316095/does-php-support-method-overloading)

Comment: Method overloading is not possible in PHP, not in the way you can overload in other languages like Java

Comment: No. However you can call other functions from the construct.

Comment: @Andrew Yes of course. I understand, but in my opinion it's a shame that it is not possible to to this in the 'normal' way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is with an optional param, as others have said in the comments, PHP does not support overloading, so this would be my suggestion:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct($p1, $p2 = null)
    {
        $this->p1 = $p1;
        $this->p2 = $p2;
    }
}
```

This means that you can choose to use `$p2` when creating the class but you must use `$p1`.

AFAIK, this is the only form of *overloading* (if you can call it that) that exists as yet in PHP

**Edit**

An extension from kingkero's answer, I came up with this solution which keeps logic out of the constructor minus a function call:

```
<?php
class overload
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        return $this->switchConstruct(func_get_args());
    }

    protected function switchConstruct(array $args)
    {
        switch (count($args))
        {
            case 0:
                return print "0 params<br />";
            case 1:
                return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'constr1'), $args);
            case 2:
                return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'constr2'), $args);
        }
        die("Invalid number of args");
    }

    protected function constr1($a) 
    {
        print "constr1 called<br />";
    }

    protected function constr2($a, $b) 
    {
        print "constr2 called<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot overload methods like that.

The best you can do is use optional parameters:

```
class testClass{

    public $param1 = "";
    public $param2 = "";

    public function __construct($param1, $param2=null){        
        $this->param1 = $param1;
        if($param2){
            $this->param2 = $param2;
        }else{
            //ToDO use function to set pramam2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I have been told many times, constructors should not contain login, so the `if` statements you use are not suitable for a constructor

Comment: @SamSwift웃 Well, constructor overloading is usually used for Poor Mans / Bastard injection, which is considered an antipattern anyway, so i dont see how this is any different http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099406/what-is-the-real-difference-between-bastard-injection-and-poor-mans-injectio

Answer (score 1):

As was already stated, you cannot do it like this. However, if you want it to be more variable than the given answers, try using [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/function.func-get-args.php) in combination with [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/function.call-user-func-array.php) like so ([demo](https://3v4l.org/fSEc3))

```
class Foo {
  public function __construct() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    switch (count($args)) {
      case 2:
        return call_user_func_array(
          array($this, 'constructorFor2Arguments'),
          $args
        );
      //...
    }
  }

  protected function constructorFor2Arguments($one, $two) {
    //...
  }
}
```