# What way to make overload in PHP

Tags: php, oop

In PHP, wa can't overload without break *PHP Strict standards*:

```
class A { 
  public function say($a, $b){
    echo "$a $b";
  } 
}

$a = new A();
$a->say('foo', 'baz'); // foo bar

class B extends A { 
  public function say($a){
    parent::z($a, 'bar');
  } 
}

$b = new B();
$b->say('foo'); // foo baz
```

What could be a good way to do this complying with *PHP Strict standards* and with a good readability/maintainability ? If it's possible to do it without ugly code ...

Comment: You can use php magic method `__call` for overloading.

Comment: check http://ar2.php.net/language.oop5.overloading

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading)

Comment: take a look http://unassumingphp.com/overloading-create-methods-on-the-fly/

Comment: You trying to ruin Liskov substitution principle, part of [SOLID]((http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)). This is not good idea.

Comment: @sectus Okay, i note it.