# PHP - how can I overload a function without using null values

Tags: php

I want to have this interface:

```
interface Resource_Controller_Interface {
    public function index_get():stdClass;
    public function index_get(mixed $key):array;
    public function index_post():bool;
    public function index_put(mixed $key):bool;
    public function index_patch(mixed $key):bool;
    public function index_delete(mixed $key):bool;
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot do two methods called 'index_get', even with different signatures.

I really want this interface to have these names though, is there a way I can do it? (using `$key = null` will not force implementation...)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading

Comment: in general, cases like this are best handled by using both an interface and an abstract class, then you can have slightly modified version of the name in the interface ( to force implementation ) and then in the abstract class have a third function that sort of brings those together, if that makes sense.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `func_num_args()` and `func_get_arg()` to get the arguments passed, and use them normally.

This way the function name will be same but you will be able to do different things using some conditionals.

Comment: I can just do `null` in this case, but why isn't the different signature allowed?

Comment: Function signatures are based only on their names and do not include argument lists, so you cannot have two functions with the same name.

Comment: dont forget `function_get_args` ( with an s )