# magic function __call function is not working

Tags: php, overloading

I am trying to work on Overloading using magic function

Here is my code:

class file1

```
    class vLiteUser{
        public function __call($methodname,$arguments)
        {
            if($methodname=='UserLogin'){
                switch(count($arguments)){
                    case 1:
                                $this->UserLogin($arguments[0]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                                $this->UserLogin($arguments[0],$arguments[1]);
                        break;
                    default:    echo "string";
                                break
                }
            }   
        }    

    public function UserLogin($data0='')
    {
        echo $data0;
    }

    public function UserLogin($data0='',$data2='')
    {   
            echo $pass
    }
} ?>
```

I have created object in another file

```
 $userObj = new vLiteUser();
 $userObj->UserLogin(data0,data1);
 $userObj->UserLogin(data0);
```

My be something I have missing and not able to find what exactly it is

Also I want to ask is private functions also covered in overloading.

Comment: You cannot have two methods with the same name in a class.

Comment: This is not how the `__call` function works. It is used to handle method calls of methods that are _not_ defined inside the given object.

Comment: Check this for alternative function overloading in php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have multiple definitions for a method in the same class.

This is wrong, and wont work no matter what visibility (public/private) you set to these methods:

```
public function UserLogin($data0='')
{
    echo $data0;
}

public function UserLogin($data0='',$data2='')
{   
    echo $pass
}
```

Besides, the magic method `__call()` will only work for undefined methods, or for methods not visible in the current scope.

So you either delete both `function UserLogin`, or you delete only one of them and make the other `private`.

Have some [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) with that.