# What is the best way to achieve the same behaviour of method overloading in PHP?

Tags: php, overloading

Suppose I have a two classes called `User` and `Product`.
Both of these need to be saved in a database.

A third class called `PersistencyHandler` handles all the database interactions (in order to obey both Single Responsability Principle and Dependency Inversion).
Here is what this class looks like:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Class PersistencyHandler
 * Handles database using PDO API
 */
class PersistencyHandler{

    /**
     * PDO connection used to save objects into.
     * @var $conn PDO
     */
    private $conn;

    /**
     * PDODatabaseSaver constructor.
     * @param $conn PDO
     */
    public function __construct($conn){
        $this->pdo = $conn;
    }

    /**
     * Saves the given object in the database
     * @param $object mixed
     */
    public function save($object){

        // as PHP does not support classic method overloading for different
        // types of objects, this is the cleanest solution I've been able to find.
        // And it's still pretty dirty...

        if($object instanceof Product) {
            $this->saveProduct($object);
        } else if($object instanceof User) {
            $this->saveUser($object);
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot save object, unsupported type."); // custom class
        }
    }


    private function saveProduct(Product $object){
        // save Product into database
    }

    private function saveUser(User $object){
        // save User into database
    }

}
?>
```

I come from Java experience and I am sure that using `instanceof` is a **very poor practice** (at least in Java). For instance, in Java, I used to solve problems like this using overloaded methods.

I have checked [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) and other websites (including this one) but I haven't found a good answer to my question:

**What is the better way to achieve the same behaviour of the above code in a correct way?**

Notice that I have a *single method* with a *single argument* and the called method is decided by the *type* of the argument.

Comment: Take a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading

Comment: Strategy pattern.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava this is not really my use case. That question is asking about overloading with different number of arguments. I always have a single argument passed to my method.

Comment: @u_mulder This pattern seems pretty interesting for this situation, thank you!

Comment: @Z.Alessandro You probably missed the first line in the accepted answer. `You cannot overload PHP functions.`

Comment: @anuragSrivastava I did not miss the first line. Your answer does not help me solving this problem.
I am asking for a way to achieve the same result with cleaner code. My title might be a bit misleading

Comment: You must edit your title to ask exactly what you are looking for :) You ask `how to do X?` and I linked to an answer which says `X isn't possible`

Comment: Did you read through the explanation of the problem? Fixed the title anyway, thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm not so knowledgeable about patterns, principles or technical language. But I'd suggest looking at how Wordpress solves this. It uses a database interaction class, and any new other objects that need to be saved implement their saving method usually through functions. For your case I really don't see the point of handling it all in one class. But as I said I'm not very technically educated.

Comment: @SarPutnik Thanks for your reply. The problem with interacting with database in different classes is the following: imagine you were using MySqli API to save things into database. What happens if you realize you'd better use PostegreSQL instead of MySQL? You would have to change **every** class. Having all in one class makes it much much easier for maintenance. I'll make sure to have a look at how Wordpress solves this!

Comment: use an interface, implement it and then extend the base class `PersistencyHandler` should really only have save and it calls the save() implemented on the child.. your making an orm basically. see how redbeanphp or such do it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Could you please provide a short example, please? I'm not sure I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use a dynamic call (similar to reflection in Java):

```
public function save($object)
{
    $mtd = 'save'.get_class($object);
    if(method_exists($this, $mtd))
        call_user_func(array($this, $mtd), $object);
    else
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot save object, unsupported type.");
}
```

Note: if you use namespaces, you will need to adapt the code (get_class() returns the qualified name).