# PHP 5.3 method overloading (like in Java)

Tags: php

In Java, we have a method overloading feature that's very useful for Singletons. For example, i have two different getInstance methods, public static, that behave differently based on the parameters received:

```
public static Currency getInstance(String currencyCode)
public static Currency getInstance(Locale locale)
```

Can we do this in PHP?

Comment: In short: No. (This answer is too short even for a comment.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is PHP function overloading for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512295/what-is-php-function-overloading-for)

Answer (score 3):

You can determine the argument type at run-time:

```
function getInstance($currency) {
   if (is_string($currency)) {
      $currency = lookupLokale($currency);
   }
   // do something with the $currency object
}
```

In php5.3+ (php5.0+ for non-static methods), you can also use php's [method overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) to implement Java-like semantics yourself. However, OOP overloading is likely to produce messy code, and you should prefer the above in-method solution.

In most cases, it's clearer if you just use two different method names.

Comment: I understand the hacks to get the same behavior, i'm using them. I just thought that maybe there was a better way.

Comment: @Jomezxn You're asking the wrong question when you're trying to map language-specific concepts from one language to another.

Answer (score 1):

Come on, at least try to Google :). Theres excellent documentation about this.
For example on the PHP site ITSELF:

EDIT: New link that describes method overloading

http://www.dinke.net/blog/en/2007/08/01/method-overloading-in-php5/

Now I got the same kind of overloading.

Comment: That's not quite the same kind of overloading as the OP wants though.

Comment: The other alternative is to use `func_get_args()` and then call the fitting implementations based on their types. However not that specific as in Java or .Net.

Comment: I really meant overloading as in having multiple functions with the same name but different parameters. I just read the page and php just refers to something different on the same name... OOP in PHP is just so broken... EDIT: Found an internet post that discusses the correct kind of overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Directly PHP don't supports method overloading, but we can implement this feature with [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

```
class Obj
{
    function __construct() {

        $args = func_get_args();

        if (count($args) != 2) {
            echo ("Must be passed two arguments !\n");
            return;
        }

        if (is_numeric($args[0]) && is_numeric($args[1])) {
            $result = $this->_addnum($args[0], $args[1]);
        }
        else if (is_string($args[0]) && is_string($args[1])) {
            $result = $this->_addstring($args[0], $args[1]);
        }
        else if (is_bool($args[0]) && is_bool($args[1])) {
            $result = $this->_addbool($args[0], $args[1]);
        }
        else if (is_array($args[0]) && is_array($args[1])) {
            $result = $this->_addarray($args[0], $args[1]);
        }
        else {
            echo ("Argument(s) type is not supported !\n");
            return;
        }

        echo "\n";
        var_dump($result);
    }

    private function _addnum($x, $y) {return $x + $y;}

    private function _addstring($x, $y) {return $x . $y;}

    private function _addbool($x, $y) {return $x xor $y;}

    private function _addarray($x, $y) {return array_merge($x,$y);}
}

// invalid constructor cases
new Obj();
new Obj(null, null);

// valid ones
new Obj(2,3);
new Obj('A','B');
new Obj(false, true);
new Obj([3], [4]);
```

Outputs :

```
Must be passed two arguments !
Argument(s) type is not supported !

int(5)
string(2) "AB"
bool(true)
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  int(3)
  [1] =>
  int(4)
}
```